# Hi! Trying to trigger a UIPath webhook from on-prem orchestrator to cloud power automate. Orchestrator displayed error "Could not connect to server""

Tags: webhooks, uipath, uipath-orchestrator

Trying to trigger a UIPath webhook from an on-prem orchestrator to a cloud power automate flow. The flow is working as I've tested it individually. Orchestrator displayed error "Could not connect to server" when an orchestrator event happened (in my case, job failure.). Is there an issue for an on-prem orchestrator to connect to cloud power automate? Kindly help.

I've triggered webhooks manually by making a orchestrator job fail. Can see error "Could not connect to server" when webhook is triggered. I expect my webhook to call a power automate flow to sent MS Teams chat